# Multirow php validation for each row

Tags: php, jquery

[image]

Please refer to the above image.. I am very new to jquery, I have developed a php form to enter data. I want to restrict user from leaving the text field if he/she enters wrong value.
Range :say 0 to 50.
It should accept AB, NR as well.

Any idea how to achieve this .

I am very much thankful for this quick reply.

I replaced

```
<script>
$.validator.addMethod("custom_number", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || value == "AB" || value == "NF" || 
value.match(/^[0-9,\+-]+$/);
}, "Please enter a valid number, or 'AB'");

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").validate({
rules: {
'hd[]': {
required: false,
custom_number: true   
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

With

```
<script>
var accept_values = array("AB","NR",'01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10');

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
var length = haystack.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
}
return false;
}

var success = 0;
$("input[type='hd[]']").each(function(){
if(!in_array(accept_values, $(this).val())) {
success = 1;
}
});
if(success == 1){
alert("You have entered an invalid value");
return false;

}
//do success
</script>
```

hoping that I can accept 01 to 10 and 'AB' and 'NR'
but it is not successful. And is there any way to provide range as well as Alphabets?

Comment: pls post the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that your textbox have same css class(eg:checkrow).

**Jquery Code(untested)**

```
  $(function(){
    var status =true;
    $('.checkrow').on('blur',function(){
    var valueofrow =$(this).val();
    if(valueofrow =='AB' || valueofrow =='NR'){
    status =true;
    } else{
    status =false;
    }
    if(status == false){
    alert("warning message");
    return false;
    } 
    });
    });
```

Comment: I wanted this (http://jsfiddle.net/M9QR3/) of effect with array ; I added   e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();this.focus();  after alert but it does not work.

Comment: sorry didnt get it,pls explain a little bit

Comment: means he cannot enter on other text field?

Comment: Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M9QR3/2/

Comment: User should not be allowed to leave the textbox if he makes entry of wrong value, He should remain in the same textbox if he enters INVALID value

Comment: check the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/M9QR3/2/

Answer (score 2):

Please modify it as per you requirement/need :

```
function validate(){
    $('.theory').each(function(){           
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                alert('Please enter value.');       
                return false;
            }else{
                if($(this).val() < 0  || $(this).val() > 50  ){
                            alert('Please enter correct value.');               
                            return false;
                     }
            }       
    });

  return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var accept_values = array("AB","NR");

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var success = 0;
$("input[type='text']").each(function(){
    if(!in_array(accept_values, $(this).val())) {
        success = 1;
    }
});
if(success == 1){
    alert("You have entered an invalid value");
    return false;
}
//do success
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your problem using jquery validator ..

check if it is as per your requirement or you want something changed ..

```
        <script src='
        http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js '></script>
        <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#frm').validate();

        $(".inp_text").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        checkValue: true
         });   
       });

            $.validator.addMethod("checkValue", function(value, element) {
            var response = ((value > 0)&&(value <= 50))||((value == 'AB')||(value =='NR'));
           return response;
           }, "invalid value");

        })

        </script>


        <form id='frm'>
        <input type='text' name='inp_text'   class='inp_text'/><br>
        <input type='text' name='inp_text1' class='inp_text'/><br>
        <input type='submit' name=''/>
        </frm>
```

note that all inputs should have same class

Comment: see http://codepad.viper-7.com/vjTo9Y  Also see http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ for jquery validator